# Show that a $2-regular$, finite, connected graph is a cycle (nontrivial)

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

**Problem:** Given a graph $G$ is non-empty, $2$-regular, finite and connected. Show that $G$ is a cycle.

**My solution:**
Firstly, we prove the corollary: $G$ non-empty, finite, connected graph such that $\deg(v) \ge 2$ for all $v \in V$. Prove that $G$ contains a nontrivial cycle. (I have proved this corollary).

Applying the corollary to the problem, $G$ contains a nontrivial cycle $C$. We prove that $G = C$.

Suppose conversely that $C \neq G$, i.e, there exists a subgraph $H$, that is not a part of the cycle $C$.

Pick a random vertex $v$ in $H$, then there exists a walk $\gamma$ from $v$ to some vertex $w$ in $C$ since $G$ is connected. Hence, $\deg(w)= 3$, which is contradict with the $2-$regular assumption.

So, $G=C$.

I wonder if there is any statement in my solution is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me. You can maybe polish a few things: for example, you can be more precise about what it means for $H$ to not be part of the cycle $C$ (perhaps, there exists a nonempty subgraph $H$ of $G-C$ or something along those lines). Also, you can replace "walk" with "path". The logic seems correct!

Comment: What is the difference between a walk and a path? I thought they are the same.

Comment: A path is a walk which contains no cycles. There is a theorem that states that if $x$ and $y$ are vertices of a graph $G$, then if there is a walk from $x$ to $y$, there is a path from $x$ to $y$ (why?).